# Calling overridable methods like Swing's add() in constructor

Tags: java, swing, constructor, overriding

I know that calling overridable methods from constructors is a bad idea. But I also see that it's being done everywhere with Swing, where code like `add(new JLabel("Something"));` occurs in constructors all the time.

Take NetBeans IDE, for example. It is very picky about overridable calls in constructors. And yet, when it generates Swing code, it puts all those `add()` method calls into an `initializeComponents()` method... which is then called from the constructor! A nice way to hide a problem and disable the warning (NetBeans doesn't have a “a private method that calls overridable methods is called from a constructor” warning). But not really a way to solve the problem.

What's going on here? I've been doing it for ages, but always had an uneasy feeling about this. Is there a better way of initializing Swing containers, except for making an additional `init()` method (and not forgetting to call it every time, which is kind of boring)?

**Example**

Here is an extremely contrived example of how things can go wrong:

```
public class MyBasePanel extends JPanel {
    public MyBasePanel() {
        initializeComponents();
    }

    private void initializeComponents() {
        // layout setup omitted
        // overridable call
        add(new JLabel("My label"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

public class MyDerivedPanel extends MyBasePanel {
    private final List<JLabel> addedLabels = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void add(Component comp, Object constraints) {
        super.add(comp);
        if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) comp;
            addedLabels.add(label); // NPE here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid wiring Swing components together in the constructor, you could simply give the responsibility of the wiring to another object.  For instance, you could give wiring duties to a Factory:

```
public class MyPanelFactory {
    public MyBasePanel myBasePanel() {
        MyBasePanel myBasePanel = new MyBasePanel();
        initMyBasePanel(myBasePanel);
        return myBasePanel;
    }

    public MyDerivedPanel myDerivedPanel() {
        MyDerivedPanel myDerivedPanel = new MyDerivedPanel();
        initMyBasePanel(myDerivedPanel);
        return myDerivedPanel;
    }

    private void initMyBasePanel(MyBasePanel myBasePanel) {
        myBasePanel.add(new JLabel("My label"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Or you could go all out and instantiate all your Swing components with a dependency injection container and have the container trigger the wiring.  Here's an example with Dagger:

```
@Module
public class MyPanelModule {
    static class MyBasePanel extends JPanel {
        private final JLabel myLabel;

        MyBasePanel(JLabel myLabel) {
            this.myLabel = myLabel;
        }

        void initComponents() {
            this.add(myLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }

    static class MyDerivedPanel extends MyBasePanel {
        private final List<JLabel> addedLabels = new ArrayList<>();

        MyDerivedPanel(JLabel myLabel) {
            super(myLabel);
        }

        @Override
        public void add(Component comp, Object constraints) {
            super.add(comp);
            if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) comp;
                addedLabels.add(label);
            }
        }
    }

    @Provides MyBasePanel myBasePanel(@Named("myLabel") JLabel myLabel) {
        MyBasePanel myBasePanel = new MyBasePanel(myLabel);
        myBasePanel.initComponents();
        return myBasePanel;
    }

    @Provides MyDerivedPanel myDerivedPanel(@Named("myLabel") JLabel myLabel) {
        MyDerivedPanel myDerivedPanel = new MyDerivedPanel(myLabel);
        myDerivedPanel.initComponents();
        return myDerivedPanel;
    }

    @Provides @Named("myLabel") JLabel myLabel() {
        return new JLabel("My label");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of OOP principles is: Prefer composition over inheritance. When I create a Swing GUI I never extend Swing components except I create a new general purpose Swing component (like a JTreeTable, JGraph, JCalendar etc.).

So my code looks like:

```
public class MyPanel {
     private JPanel mainPanel;
     public MyPanel() {
         init();
     }
     private void init() {
          mainPanel = new JPanel();
     }
     public Component getComponent() {
         return mainPanel;
     }
}

public class MyComposedPanel {
     private JPanel mainPanel;
     public MyComposedPanel() {
         init();
     }
     private void init() {
          mainPanel = new JPanel();
          mainPanel.add(new MyPanel().getComponent());
     }
     public Component getComponent() {
         return mainPanel;
     }
}
```

This way has one disadvantage: there is no GUI builder which supports it ;)

Comment: Is this really the only disadvantage? How do you add your component to a container? Code like `frame.add(myPanel.getComponent())` looks weird to me.

Comment: For me it's not a disadvantage. I get more disadvantage if I see over 100 methods in proposal pop-up of my Eclipse, which are derived from JComponent.

Comment: Looks like a violation of Demeter's principle to me. By working directly with whatever `getComponent()` returns you're “talking to a stranger”. If you use composition, the component should be encapsulated. That is, if it's really composition. Your example looks more like the Builder Pattern to me, which is a much better idea.

Comment: It's a little bit more than builder. In my programms, it makes also getting/setting of data to the widgets and conversion of low-level swing events to the high-level program events. But it seems, that we have different understanding of OOP, so you can continue to use GUI builder ;)

Answer (score 1):

Coming back after a while and reading the accepted answer, I realized that there is an even simpler way of solving this issue. If the responsibility of calling overridable methods can be moved off to another class, it can also be moved off to a static method, using the factory method pattern:

```
class MyBasePanel extends JPanel {

    public static MyBasePanel create() {
        MyBasePanel panel = new MyBasePanel();
        panel.initializeComponents();
        return panel;
    }

    protected MyBasePanel() {
    }

    protected void initializeComponents() {
        // layout setup omitted
        // overridable call
        add(new JLabel("My label"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

class MyDerivedPanel extends MyBasePanel {

    private final List<JLabel> addedLabels = new ArrayList<>();

    public static MyDerivedPanel create() {
        MyDerivedPanel panel = new MyDerivedPanel();
        panel.initializeComponents();
        return panel;
    }

    protected MyDerivedPanel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Component comp, Object constraints) {
        super.add(comp);
        if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) comp;
            addedLabels.add(label); // no more NPE here
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, one still has to remember to call `initializeComponents` when subclassing, but at least not every time an instance is created! Properly documented, this approach can be both simple and reliable.

Answer (score -2):

Netbeans is generating the function private.

```
private initializeComponents() {...}
```

Thus the method is not overridable. Only protected and public methods are overridable.

An extra function keeps your code much cleaner for the Netbeans expample.
But in general you can savely use private methods to initialize classes.

Moreover if you have multiple constructors it's practical to use one extra method for initialization.

```
class Foo {

   int x,y;
   String bar;

   public Foo(x) {
      this.x = x;
      init();
   }

   public Foo(y) {
      this.y = y;
      init();
   }
   private void init() {
      // .. something complicated or much to do
      bar = "bla";
   }
}
```

Comment: It may keep code cleaner, but it doesn't make it *safer*. On the contrary, the problem is hidden now, but it's still there. Even though the init function is private, the functions it calls, like `add()`, are not. So if someone overrode `add()`, you'd have exactly the same problem, only hidden away in a private function! That's the point of my question.